# Find a ring with nonzero elements $a,b,c$ such that $ab=ca=0$ but $ba\neq 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is there any element $a$ in a ring $R$ with identity (non commutative) such that $aR = Ra$ with non zero elements $b$ and $c$ in $R$ having the property that $ab = 0$, $ba\ne 0$, but $ca = 0$?

Comment: think about ring of matrices.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I see someone already edited your post, but for some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

There is an example (that is apparently what you're looking for) of a ring with $8$ elements satisfying this. Take $R$ to be the upper triangular matrices over the field $F_2$ of two elements.

Let $a=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

You have that $aR=Ra=\begin{bmatrix}0&F_2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Let $b=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Then you have $ab=0$ and $ba=a\neq 0$.

For $c$ you can use $c=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

---

A ring in which $ab=0$ implies $ba=0$ for all elements $a,b$ is called  a *reversible ring*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If we insist on normalizing elements b and c, can we have example?

Comment: @user689490 By normalizing, do you mean they have to satisfy all the same conditions as $a$?